# Vim autocomplete a struct in C

Tags: c, vim, autocomplete

I'm trying to use Vim autocomplete. I've got a `struct` in file `def.h`:

```
typedef struct test{
        int x;
        int y;
}*test_p,test_t;
```

And in the corresponding C file:

```
test_p t;
t->[autocomplete here]
```

What i should press to fill it with x or y? Neither <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> nor <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> give me variables from inside `test`.

I've already used `ctags` and of course I've included `def.h`. Here is what is in my tags file:

```
test    def.h   /^typedef struct test{$/;"      s
test_p  def.h   /^}*test_p,test_t;$/;"  t       typeref:struct:test
test_t  def.h   /^}*test_p,test_t;$/;"  t       typeref:struct:test
x       def.h   /^      int x;$/;"      m       struct:test
y       def.h   /^      int y;$/;"      m       struct:test
```

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for omni-complete (`Ctrl-X Ctrl-O`).

`Ctrl-P` or `Ctrl-N` only autocomplete words from current files/buffers. You want intelisense (R) (omnicomplete) introduced in vim 7 I believe. See [C++ code completion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C%2B%2B_code_completion) - not sure if that helps.